# Removing scientific notation from float

Tags: ruby

I'm currently multiplying two floats like so: 0.0004 * 0.0000000000012 = 4.8e-16

How do I get the result in a normal format, i.e. without the scientific notation, something like 0.0000000000324 and then round it up to say 5 numbers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [string formatting](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-25).

```
a =  0.0004 * 0.0000000000012 # => 4.8e-16
'%.5f' % a # => "0.00000"

pi = Math::PI # => 3.141592653589793
'%.5f' % pi # => "3.14159"
```

Comment: this returns a string, i want it to return a float as well. if I do "0.00001".to_f ... it returns back a float in scientific notation

Comment: Floats don't have notation, they are numbers. It's their on-screen representation that can be scientific notation, a stream of ones and zeroes or whatever.